# How to set SOAP_ACTION and WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE?

Tags: java, web-services

I'm creating a sample web service using visual studio.
When i run the web service the path is = **http://localhost:62558/SmartPosterV1.asmx**.
My Operation name is = **HelloWorld()**.
How do i get **SOAP_ACTION** and **WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE**?

```
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://localhost:62558/SmartPosterV1.asmx";
private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "HelloWorld";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = ?
private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = ?
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You do need the WSDL (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) file specifying the way the SOAP Webservice can be accessed by a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I published the web service in server and call it from server. Problem solved. Thanks.

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sposter.smartag.my/getFileName";
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://sposter.smartag.my/WebService1.asmx";
private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://sposter.smartag.my";
private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "getFileName";
```